# Regular Expression (RegEx) For Hours with Increments

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need to only accept input that meets these rules...

1. 0.25-24
2. Increments of .25 (.00, .25, .50, .75)
3. First digit doesn't have to be required.
4. Would like trailing zeros to be optional.

Examples of some valid entries:

1. 0.25
2. .50
3. .5
4. 1
5. 1.0
6. 5.50
7. 23.75
8. 24 (max allowed)
9. **UPDATE:** nothing at all, null/blank, should also be accepted as valid

Example of some invalid entries:

1. 0
2. .0
3. .00
4. 0.0
5. 0.00
6. 24.25
7. -1

I understand that RegEx is a pattern matching language therefore it's not great for ranges, less-than, and great-than checking.  So to check if it's less than or equal to 24 means I'd have to find a pattern, right?  So there are 24 possible patters which would make this a long RegEx, am I understanding this correctly?  I could use ColdFusion to do the check to make sure it's in the 0-24 range.  It's not the end of the world if I have use ColdFusion for this part, but it'd be nice to get it all into the RegEx if it doesn't cause it to be too long.  This is what I have so far:

`^\d{0,2}((\.(0|00|25|5|50|75))?)$`

**http://regex101.com/r/iS7zM3**

This handles pretty much all of it except for the 0-24 range check or the check for just a zero. I'll keep plugging away at it but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, is it okay to allow an empty string to pass?

Comment: Good catch, yes it is okay, yours and Peter's answer allow `{null}` so all is good.

Comment: Hmm, mine shouldn't be matching empty strings... I guess I don't full understand how CF handles regex =/

Comment: Oh you're right, your's doesn't, sorry, I missed that.  Yes, blank/null should be valid.  If you could adjust your answer to allow that for reference sake I'd appreciate it.  Both answers were really helpful.

Comment: To allow empty string for any pattern you can prefix with `^$|` - or to _prevent_ empty string change `^` to `^(?!$)` in relevant sections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `\d{0,2}` to `(?:1[0-9]?|2[0-4]?|[3-9])?` and it'll match from 1 to 24 (or nothing).

You can also simplify the second part to `(?:\.(?:00?|25|50?|75))?` - you could go further to `(?:\.(?:[05]0?|[27]5))?` but that might obfuscate the intent a bit too far.

To exclude 24.25 you could perhaps use a negative lookahead `(?!24\.[^0])` to prevent anything other than 24.0 or 24.00, but it's probably simpler to just exclude 24 from the main pattern and include a specific check for 24/24.0/24.00 at the start:

```
(?x)
    # checks for 24
    ^24$|^24\.00?$
    |
    # integer part
    ^
    (?:1[0-9]?|2[0-3]?|[3-9]|0(?=\.[^0])|(?=\.[^0]))
    # decimal part
    (?:\.(?:00?|25|50?|75))?
    $
```

That also includes a check for `0(?=\.[^0])` which uses a positive lookahead to only allow an initial `0` if the next char is a `.` followed by a non-zero (so 0.0 and 0.00 isn't allowed).

The `(?x)` flag allows whitespace to be ignored, allowing readable regex in your code - obviously preferable to squashing it all onto a single line - and also enables the use of `#` to start line comments to explain parts of a pattern. <sub>(Literal whitespaces and hashes can be escaped with backslash, or encoded via e.g. `\x23` for hash.)</sub>

For comparison, here's a pure-CFML way of doing it:

```
IsNumeric(Num)
AND Num GT 0
AND Num LTE 24
AND NOT find('.',Num*4)
```

Now, are you really sure it's better as a regex...

Comment: I think it will match 24.25,... also.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that after posting, have just updated to fix that. Doh... just noticed I missed 0.25 though... that should be fixed too.

Comment: In your RegEx, what is the colon (:) for?  I don't need real time format (obviously 12:75 isn't a valid time), instead users enter in numeric fractions of time, eg, 12.75 (which would equate to 12hrs and 45min).

Comment: There is no literal colon. `(?:`...`)` is a non-capturing group - the same as `(`...`)` but without storing the sub-match. [More info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Yes, the CFML way is simple, but the CF validation framework I've created allows RegEx to be passed in, so it'd be shorter from a coding stand-point.  Thanks, I learned some stuff from this post!  I did plug your RegEx into this site: **http://regex101.com/r/tG7lN6** , everything tested out fine but I don't understand the result text, can you explain: "No match groups were extracted. This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string."  Thanks!

Comment: That message just means there's no capturing groups (as described in link on my previous comment) - it's nothing to worry about; you only need capturing groups if you want to extract sub-sections of the match or for back-references - neither of which are necessary for validation of a value.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I like your CF only solution. Never would have thought of multiplying `num * 4` to see if it was a correct fraction

Answer (score 3):

You could try this regex (broken down):

```
^
(?:
(?:[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3])(?:\.(?:[05]0?|[27]5))?   # Non-zeros with optional decimal
|
0?(?:\.(?:50?|[27]5))                         # Decimals under 1
|
24(?:\.00?)?                                  # The maximum
)
$
```

In one line:

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3])(?:\.(?:[05]0?|[27]5))?|0?(?:\.(?:50?|[27]5))|24(?:\.00?)?)$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cJ1tK3)

Comment: This one seems to pass all my tests as well, wish I could award two answers.  Thank you.

Comment: @gfrobenius No worries, thank you leaving a comment :)

Comment: @gfrobenius By the way, capture groups are special groups that can be used after the match has been complete. In this case, there is only validation going on, so capture groups are no necessary. Otherwise, they'd take a bit more of your available memory!

Answer (score 0):

`^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4])((\.(0|00|25|5|50|75))?)$`

This means the one's place can be 0-9 if the tens place is missing, a 0, or 1.

If the tens place is a 2, then the ones place can be 0-4.

The second part is great, it's simple and readable too.  It has an extra set of parens though that can be removed, reducing it to this:

`^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4])(\.(0|00|25|5|50|75))?$`

Comment: This regex will consider "0" "0.0" and "0.00" valid, which you said those should not be valid.  Looks like Jerry's answer is the most accurate, even though it's quite complicated.  It depends if you need it all in a regex, or if you are willing to do a separate test for 0.

Comment: Using `2[0-4]` will allow `24.25` and such.